# Jenkins Pipeline - Sending/showing credentials password value in clear text

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a username and a password configured in Jenkins Credentials.
When I use withcredentials in my pipeline, my log output shows ***** in passwords.

But, if I write an email to me, with this credentials, I receive an clear text password.

```
stage('Migrations - BD Integracao'){
    steps {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'CREDENTIAL_ID', variable: 'PWD')]) {
            emailext body: 'password: '+PWD, 
                subject: 'Discovering password', 
                to: 'myemail@site.com'
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is a vulnerability, because everyone who can write a pipeline script can send an email to discovery the passwords.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: `Mask Passwords` (`withCredentials()`) is a pure console log filter. A console log filter is not applied to content of code internal logical variables. It purely targets output that is written to logs. What you describe is out of the scope of that plugin.

Comment: Adding to the above - a Jenkins job can do all sorts of malicious things whether it is a pipeline or a freestyle job. Most systems of this sort have the same issue.  If you are concerned about this kind of abuse, you may need to restrict who can create new jobs.